# Passing the return of a function as a parameter by reference in PHP?

Tags: php, return-value, pass-by-reference, argument-passing

**THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE, READ THE QUESTION MORE CAREFULLY**
It's about the possibility to pass by value when the argument is marked as by-reference.

---

In PHP you can pass the return value of a function as a by-reference parameter to another function.

For example:

```
function dummy(){}

function myFunc(&$var){ // argument by reference
    echo $var ;
}

myFunc('some value') ; // this line gives an error obviously, not a reference
myFunc(dummy('some value')) ; // but this one does not, why?
```

Why is it possible to do that?
What is the intended use for it?

Comment: no, it's definitely not a duplicate. The question is not what the `&` symbol is, it's a more deep question.

Answer (score 2):

Your second example gives a strict standards warning:

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in X on line Y
```

I believe this is done for backwards compatibility, since this previously generated no warnings:

```
$last = end( explode( ',', $csv_string));
```

So, in order to not break that code, your example emits a warning, but continues on. Even the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) states that:

> No other expressions should be passed by reference, as the result is undefined.